# How to make automatic pull request with Sourcetree NOT in master branch?

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I just wondering is there an option in **SourceTree** to change the default branch of automatic pull requests.

[image: SourceTree pull request]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using SourceTree & github the answer seems to be <strike>no :(</strike>  Yes ! see the last part of my answer !

The documentation of attlasian says that you can do that in BitBucket if the admin has allowed that option 
(https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Work+with+pull+requests)

> If you are pulling a request across branches, you can have the option
>   to close the branch when your request is merged. Whether you have this
>   option depends on whether the repository is Git or Mercurial.
>   Mercurial repositories always have this option. Git repositories have
>   this option if the repo administrator allows it; Otherwise, the option
>   is greyed out.

In other hand if you are working with github you can do that manually.

[Merge pull request to a different branch than default, in Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135913/merge-pull-request-to-a-different-branch-than-default-in-github)

---Edit:

Looking deep i found that when you create your PullRequest in github you can select which will be your branch used as "base" 
[image]

Comment: Probably related, hope I can revive the discussion.                                                                                                          I am not an admin, can't tell you about more specifics of our settings, but we use git & github.                                                                                           My doubt is about making several "pull requests". Seems that after my first pull request was accepted and merged to our main, github doesn't provide s the option to make a second pull request anymore.

Comment: Is it that once merged,  my branch was locked? Even if I can continue doing commits to that branch?  The reason for a second pull request, is that I made a mistake and have to merge once more. I know one solution is to create a new branch from the merged and another pull request round from it, but that's not about.  Thanks.

Comment: According to this workflow, it is not possible to do that even with topic branches, anyone can confirm it?   [git & github workflow on topic branches](https://blog.reigndesign.com/blog/creating-and-deleting-topic-branches-with-git-and-github/)

Comment: Hi @notNullGothik, Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674304/github-reopening-a-merged-pull-request

Comment: Thanks! Most rated answer is NO, but actually revert might be the only possible solution.