# How to re-open merged pull-request in Github?

Tags: git, github

I opened PR and accidentely merge it into another branch. After than, I reverted this merge (via `git revert hash -m 1`) and wanna re-open my PR. But I don't see re-open button. Also there weren't revert button near my merge. What can I do to re-open PR (it has code reviews, comments, etc. and I can't just create a new PR).

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Once it is merged and closed it can't be reopened.

More details you can find under:

[GitHub: Reopening a merged pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674304/github-reopening-a-merged-pull-request/12838195#12838195)

Comment: What's your suggestion?

Comment: You'd need to open a new PR, since the existing one can't be reopened once merged.  It may be inconvenient, but it's the only option.