# In GitHub, how do I make a suggested change on a merged PR when I don't have write access to the repository?

Tags: github

[This PR](https://github.com/ayonious/console-table-printer/pull/458/files) was created in response to [an issue I made](https://github.com/ayonious/console-table-printer/issues/456). I don't have write access to [this repo](https://github.com/ayonious/console-table-printer). The PR has already been merged into the main branch, but I'd like to suggest a change anyway; [here's one of the modifications in that PR](https://github.com/ayonious/console-table-printer/pull/458/files?diff=unified&w=0#diff-b335630551682c19a781afebcf4d07bf978fb1f8ac04c6bf87428ed5106870f5L40-R41):

```js
-  { index: 3, text: 'I would like some gelb bananen bitte', value: 100 },
-  { index: 4, text: 'I hope batch update is working', value: 300 },
+  { Rank: 3, text: 'I would like some Yellow', value: 100 },
+  { Rank: 4, text: 'I hope batch update is working', value: 300 },
```

I'd like to suggest this change in casing (`Rank` to `rank`):

```js
-  { Rank: 3, text: 'I would like some Yellow', value: 100 },
-  { Rank: 4, text: 'I hope batch update is working', value: 300 },
+  { rank: 3, text: 'I would like some Yellow', value: 100 },
+  { rank: 4, text: 'I hope batch update is working', value: 300 },
```

But when I click on the <kbd>+</kbd> button to submit a comment, I don't see [the "Suggest Change" button described in the official documentation (see step 6)](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests/commenting-on-a-pull-request#adding-comments-to-a-pull-request):

[image]

This is what my editor looks like:

[image]

I don't have a lot of experience with GitHub Pull Requests. For all I know:

1. This is working as intended because of some sort of repository setting.
2. This is working as intended because you can't modify a PR after it's been merged? I know *git* can merge from one branch to another multiple times, but I also know PR !== `git merge`: this may be irrelevant.
3. This is a GitHub bug. [I found other GitHub users reporting the same problem](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/7128), but that's in a community post without an official response, and despite the comments, I think this is a feature request, not a bug report. But—and I say this with all due respect—those users may *think* they are experiencing a bug but the site is working as intended.

Many of those comments say the suggestion feature still works even though the button is missing. That's part of their complaint: they have to manually type "```suggestion" into the editor.

---

#### Updates

[I've dragged in a different way that fixed the issue for a commenter below](https://github.com/ayonious/console-table-printer/pull/458/files#diff-b335630551682c19a781afebcf4d07bf978fb1f8ac04c6bf87428ed5106870f5R40-R41), but it still doesn't work for me:

[image]

Just in case this has to do with a suggestion already being made on those lines, [I tried the same thing on a different set of added lines.](https://github.com/ayonious/console-table-printer/pull/458/files?diff=split&w=0#diff-b335630551682c19a781afebcf4d07bf978fb1f8ac04c6bf87428ed5106870f5R65-R66) Still missing the suggestion button:

[image]

I should also add, [it makes no difference if I hit the + button without dragging or drag from/to a single line](https://github.com/ayonious/console-table-printer/pull/458/files#diff-b335630551682c19a781afebcf4d07bf978fb1f8ac04c6bf87428ed5106870f5R65):

[image]

Comment: I see the button, but hovering over it gives "Applying suggestions on deleted lines is not supported." Instead I created a new comment over the new lines, and manually created the suggestion. All the button does is insert a markdown code-block (in triple backticks) with the language set to `suggestion` https://github.com/ayonious/console-table-printer/pull/458/files#r1435398922

Comment: @Alexander But when you look at my *screenshot*, aren't I already creating a new comment over a new line? I clicked on 5-10 plus buttons on new lines and none of them showed the "suggestion" button.

Comment: I’m not sure why, but it appears to have also grabbed some deleted lines too

Comment: @Alexander [in my *screenshot*?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ojt2i.png) What part of the picture tells you that?

Comment: I didn't see it in screenshot, but there is a diff when I visit the page. Notice that on your comment, it says "Commented on lines -40 to +41", but on mine it says "Commented on lines +40 to +41". I was able to recreate your comment by dragging from line 40 on the left, to line 41 on the right, leading to this link: https://github.com/ayonious/console-table-printer/pull/458/files#diff-b335630551682c19a781afebcf4d07bf978fb1f8ac04c6bf87428ed5106870f5L40-R41 By comparison, I made my comment by stating with 40 on the right, til 41 on the right. THe link is the same, but ends with `R40-R41` instead

Comment: @Alexander  `I was able to recreate your comment by dragging from line 40 on the left, to line 41 on the right` Interesting, because that is *not* how I dragged to create my comment. Though I may have dragged from 41 on the right up to 40 on the right. Regardless, I dragged, clicked the + button, and the top of the comment box said, "Commenting on lines +40 to +41," but I still don't see the suggestion button. I'll add this screenshot to the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that on a merged Pull Request. What you can do instead is fork the repository, make the change on your fork, and open a new Pull Request.

I did some experimentation on a repository, and the rule seems to be that you can only create or apply suggested changes on a Pull Request which is open, and not merged or closed.

This is what the suggested change button looks like after creating a new pull request:

[image: pull request feedback with suggested changes button]

Then, after the pull request is closed:

[image: pull request feedback, no button]

After the PR is reopened:

[image: pull request feedback with suggested changes button]

And this is what it looks like after merging the PR:

[image]

This shows that the thing preventing you from making suggested changes is the PR status. Since you can't [re-open a merged pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12674304/github-reopening-a-merged-pull-request), you can't make a suggested change on this PR.

Even if you could make the suggestion, the button for applying the change is greyed out when the PR is closed or merged.

The best you can do is make a new Pull Request.